What is better XML mapper or Built-In QueryWrapper methods in myBatis plus
// using list()
List<TaskOrder> taskOrders = taskOrderService.list(new QueryWrapper<TaskOrder>()
                .eq("task_id", id));

// using mapper
List<TaskOrder> taskOrders = taskOrderService.getBaseMapper().getTaskOrderList(id);

this is the mapper file (only extracted code is in here)

    <select id="getTaskOrderList"  resultType="com.wonder.app.domain.TaskOrder">
        select *
        from sn_task_order
            where task_id = #{task_id}
    </select>

what is the recommended way to use when only one table data data retrieving ?
